# Selecting the top 10% of the raked values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I select the top 10% of ranked values in an array? 
The array is already raked and I can choose a number of top raked values from it.  For example I can choose a number of values using the sublist as follow

```
array = array.subList(0,100);
```

but I could not choose the 10% of the ranked values as the function (`sublist`) require integers for its parameters

Comment: What will be the 10% of when array length is 45? Is not it 4.5? In that case what you want to select 0 to 3 or 0 to 4? 4.5 is not a valid index.

Comment: Could you clarify your question with an example?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly `array = array.subList(0,array.size() / 10);` should work fine (assuming array has at least 10 elements).

`array.size() / 10` will return an integer, as it is an integer division. What happens when `array.size()` is less than 10 is that this will return an empty list (as the integer division will return 0).

Comment: TAhanks@federico . yes that is what I am looking for. but there is no array,length. May be you mean array.size()

Comment: @aya yes, you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I was still reasoning on arrays when I wrote that part (in the comment), not on `List`s, and it carried over in the answer.

Comment: I am not care about the array size because it always greater than 10. I am working with huge dataset.

Comment: Even better. Just consider that the division is rounded down, so, e.g., 10% of 100, 101, 102, 103, 104... 109 is still 10.